# JSP Page reloads with form submit - dynamic data not displayed

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

I am new to JSP. I have a JSP page with form (Two text fields) on click of Search button, I am submitting the form and calling a Javascript function with in same JSP and in that function I have a scriptlet which connects to database and retrives user data as Arraylist. Now I am trying to push this array list values into Javascript. When I click on Search I dont see these values in GUI (form) but view source has values. Can anyone help me how to solve this issue? I guess this is because page reload but how to show up that data.

```
var UIDset = [];
var Nameset = [];
var OrgIDset = [];
<%
String uidValue="";
String orgIDValue="";
int i=0;
if(request.getParameter("UID")!=null)
    uidValue=request.getParameter("UID");
if(request.getParameter("OrgID")!=null)
    orgIDValue=request.getParameter("OrgID");
RetriveUserData rs = new RetriveUserData(uidValue, orgIDValue);
List<UserDetails> l=new ArrayList<>();
l=rs.performSearch();
%>
for(UserDetails ud : l)
{ 
%>
        UIDset.push(<%=ud.uid%>);
        Nameset.push(<%=ud.gName%>);
        OrgIDset.push(<%=ud.orgVal%>);
<%
}
%>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this issue?